# appending a list with using input values in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two list, an empty list(newgr) and the other got values that has been imported from an excel sheet(gr). I'm trying to iterate through the list in a for-loop so that I can compare and change some of the values and append the values in gr that have changed with the original values into newgr. I tried this format but it wasn't working.

```
df = pd.read_excel("Well_Logs.xlsx", "SB16", na_values = [-999])
newgr = []
gr = df['GR'].values.tolist()

grclean = int(input('enter your clean value >')) #20 for example
grclay = int(input('enter your clay value >')) #60 for example

for i in gr:

    if i < grclean:
        i==grclean
        newgr.append(i)
    elif i > grclay:
        i==grclay
        newgr.append(i)
    else:
        newgr.append(i)

print(newgr)
```

I'm expecting the list to have some new values to work with, rather the same values of gr is appended to newgr.

Comment: Just for clarification, when you print newgr, you only get the values that are in gr right?

Comment: Yes. I'm expecting to some of the values to change.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```py
i = grclean
```

to assign `grclean` to `i`

instead of

```py
i == grclean
```

which is a comparison.

You can also write the entire loop as a neat list comprehension:

```py
newgr = [max(grclean, min(grclay, i)) for i in gr]
```

Comment: I tried this code on its own and it worked but it gave me an error when I ran it as part of my script.

Comment: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Your list contains `None`s then.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel("Well_Logs.xlsx", "SB16", na_values = [-999])
newgr = []
gr = df['GR'].values.tolist()

grclean = int(input('enter your clean value >')) #20 for example
grclay = int(input('enter your clay value >')) #60 for example

for i in gr:

    if i < grclean:
        newgr.append(grclean)
    elif i > grclay:
        newgr.append(grclay)
    else:
        newgr.append(i)

print(newgr)
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense